# Getting "Cannot GET /" in browser with express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Working with express Router for getting for the first time.
This is my route.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('home page');
});
module.exports = router;
```

This is my index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router=require('./route.js');
app.use('/route',router);
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT ||8000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});
```

When I open run it in browser it shows: 
    Cannot GET /

Comment: But you are calling `http://localhost:8000/route` ?

Comment: I was calling  http://localhost:8000

Comment: Okay than that's the problem. You registered your router for `/route`. Express basically concats the paths which in your case is `/route` (index.js) + `/`(route.js) = `/route`. So just change `/route` to `/` in index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only URL the code you have written will respond to is:

```
www.example.com/route/
```

---

If you want it to respond to:

```
www.example.com
```

then change to the following in your `index.js` file:

```
app.use('/', router);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace 
app.use('/route',router); with app.use('/', router);

Answer (score 1):

As I may see you have created default route in app.use as /route

you must not have added that using app.use('/') would be enough instead of creating another route for that

Thanks.